# Play WAV files using SoundManager2 (cross-browser)

Tags: javascript, .net, flash, wav, soundmanager2

Background:

I have a service that downloads sound media from a cloud service to a local drive. This media is served through an ajax-powered website. The mimetype of the sound files can be aac, m4a and wav!

Issue:

IE does not support playing wav files directly, so I'm using SoundManager2 with flash support - however, this does not appear to be working.

This is the output I get from SoundManager2 flash debug when I load it:

```
SM2 SWF V2.97a.20150601 (AS3/Flash 9)
ExternalInterface available
Adding ExternalInterface callbacks...
Testing Flash -> JS...
Flash -> JS OK
Waiting for JS -> Flash...
JS -> Flash OK
Enabling polling, 50 ms interval
```

This is the chrome console output:

```
SoundManager V2.97a.20150601 (AS3/Flash 9) + debugFlash
VM12007:1293 SoundManager 2 loaded (OK) ✓
```

And when I try to play a file:

```
 (Flash): SoundManager2_SMSound_AS3: Got duration: 0, autoPlay: false
```

The file exists and I can play it (in chrome only) by opening the link directly in the browser.

This is the code I use to set up SoundManager2:

```
soundManager.setup({
    url: 'path/to/swfs/',
    flashVersion: 9,
    useHTML5Audio: false,
    debugMode: true,
    debugFlash: true,
    useFlashBlock: false,
    onready: function () {
        // Converts links to playable audio.
        // http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/basic.html
        var inlinePlayer = new InlinePlayer();
    }
});
```

Comment: did you created a smSound Object with the file, so you can launch the play() action?

Comment: IE wouldn't play the file no matter what even if I forced the flash player. It turns out flash doesn't natively support WAV files either. So I implemented media conversion in the service that downloads the wav files so that all files are now mp3.